BlueZ: How to safely copy storage directory after each bonding?
I'm writing firmware for a device whose only persistent storage is flash memory. Because the reliability of flash memory cells decreases at every write and erase cycle, I can't just let BlueZ write directly to it (which it does every time a bonded device connects).
My device currently stores BlueZ's storage directory (/var/lib/bluetooth/) on RAM through tmpfs. Now, I need to copy this directory to persistent storage whenever a bonding happens (BlueZ emits a D-Bus PropertiesChanged signal on its org.bluez.Device1 interface whenever it bonds with a remote device) so that my device remembers the keys. Then I'll just have to copy the storage directory from persistent storage back to /var/lib/bluetooth/ right before starting bluetoothd.
I guess I can't just cp -u anytime as there would be data corruption if I do this while BlueZ is writing. My question is: how and when can I do this copy without risking data corruption due to reading these files while BlueZ is modifying them?
I'm using BlueZ 5.55.
Please note that:

I can't postpone the copy to when bluetoothd stops as user can easily hard shutdown;
I'm aware I could stop bluetoothd, copy, then restart bluetoothd, but I'd like to avoid doing that as it would be a pain to manage.


stupid question: do you see something specific happening in udevadm monitor when you bond a device? I see in bluez's src/device.c that there's definitely dbus messages being flung around when a device bonds, so you could just wait for these. The problem with not interfering with bluetoothd's operation when copying is relatively easy to solve with a combination of three things:

instead of just mounting a tmpfs over /var/lib/bluetooth, mount a tmpfs elsewhere, and use it for an overlayfs that "absorbs" changes to /var/lib/bluetooth
whenever you see a bonding dbus message, copy the


resulting file from the merged /var/lib/bluetooth to some separate permanent location. 3. On boot, move the files from the separate permanent location to the permanent storage that backs the lower layer of the overlayfs-merged /var/lib/bluetooth before mounting the overlayfs. (Changes to lower layers in overlayfs are illegal while it's mounted).

@MarcusMüller Thank you for your comment. I should have made it clearer in my question (I'll edit it), but I'm already able to know when a bonding happens (BlueZ emits this event as a D-Bus PropertiesChanged signal on its org.bluez.Device1 interface). My question is about how I can do the copy from /var/lib/bluetooth without risking data corruption due to reading these files while BlueZ is modifying them.

BlueZ simply isn't modifying them, once bonding has happened? That's at least my understanding. The Dbus message happens after successful bonding, which involves writing out and closing that file.

@MarcusMüller There's unfortunately a (device-specific) file that BlueZ rewrites whenever a bonded device connects. Even if I copy right after a successful bonding, there's always a risk that another device connects at the same time. However… If I only copy the files that correspond to the just-bonded device, there might be no risk of corruption at all? It seems I have no other choice than following this track. Thank you for your help Marcus!
